# Rebus puzzle with four colored bars and diagonals between them

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, rebus, computer-puzzle

This is an extremely simple rebus puzzle, the answer is extremely obvious if you know where to seek, you only need some lateral thinking, and maybe some basic programming knowledge.

[image]

To make it even simpler:

> The answer consists of two English words.

There will be no more hints, otherwise the puzzle will be way too easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zooming in on the image reveals that the coloured lines actually consist of small boxes, so given the rest of the clues, we must be talking about the words

> **Stack Exchange**

Which we can indeed see in an obvious spot:

> [image]

Comment: Could you please clarify this answer? Perhaps by giving a definition of the words and/or explaining how they apply to the puzzle?

Comment: The position of two stacks of of colored squares are being exchanged.  Hence, "Stack Exchange".